WebRTC connection works only for local network or same network
I am working on a video calling application using WebRTC, ReactJS and NestJS. My video calling is working perfect on localhost within different browser windows and also works on live server if internet is same but it fails to connect for remote connections. Given below is my RTC connection code:
addPeerConnection(id, stream, callback) {
    this.peerConnections[id] = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
      ],
    });
    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      this.senders.push(this.peerConnections[id].addTrack(track, stream));
    });
    this.listeners[id] = (event) => {
      const fn = this['_on' + capitalizeFirstLetter(this.peerConnections[id].connectionState)];
      fn && fn(event, id);
    };
    this.peerConnections[id].addEventListener('connectionstatechange', this.listeners[id]);
    this.peerConnections[id].ontrack = function ({ streams: [stream] }) {
      console.log({ id, stream });
      callback(stream);
    };
    console.log("Listen Peer coming",this.peerConnections);
  }

this is in my class component. Any help would be appreciated.
I am trying to achieve it for remote videos connection.

Remember that you must configure a "Turn server" and "Stun server" service, for example with "Coturn".
Doing so will help you overcome connection problems when working with different networks, firewalls, etc.
Example config coturn:
...
    this.peerConnections[id] = new RTCPeerConnection({
              iceServers: [
                    { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                    {
                          urls: 'turn:yourTURN.com:port',
                          credential: 'password',
                          username: 'username'
                    }
              ],
    });
...

